# How to add image and text into table

Tags: html

I am trying to make a 1x2 table and include a picture into one cell and some text into the other. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or am missing something. But the image appears but the text doesn't...

HTML Code:

```
<div id="PurpleBacking"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
    <th><img src="MoneyIcon.png"> </th>
        <th> This is a test</th>
        </tr>    
    </table>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could please provide style rules also if using any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `<td>` instead of`<th>` in case you want a paragraph or more since `<th>` is for a header in the table.

So it should be like this:

```
<div id="PurpleBacking"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
    <td><img src="MoneyIcon.png"> </td>
        <td> This is a test</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</div>
```